# Getting a new list from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Starting with a list of dictionary objects, how can I get a new list containing just some of the dictionary values, based on the keys?

For example:

```
my_list = [ {'foo':1},{'bar':2},{'foo':3} ]
new_list = grab_values(my_list, 'foo')
```

What we want:

```
new_list = [1, 3]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first that comes to mind is:

```
In [2]: [x['foo'] for x in my_list if 'foo' in x]
Out[2]: [1, 3]
```

As a function:

```
In [3]: def grab_values(l, key):
   ...:     return [x[key] for x in l if key in x]
   ...: 

In [4]: grab_values(my_list, 'foo')
Out[4]: [1, 3]
```

Comment: Yes I just used it for the example, never in my real code. Edited the OP.

Comment: @user11177 Good :) removed the notice. You can remove the comment.

Comment: Seems like I'm not allowed.. maybe not enough rep.

Comment: @user11177 You mean you don't see a little grey cross when you hover over your comment? Anyway, it's no big deal

Comment: Yes but nothing happens when I click it.